# Pulling metadate from url with php, strange characters?

Tags: metadata, external

I'm having a bit of an issue, im trying to pull basic metadata from an external URL, I have successfuly got it to do so for the most part but its causing a few character issues on letters that are Ä ä ö are coming out like mÃ¤enjaksa7-300x200.jpg when i call the images url which is actually mäenjaksa7-300x200.jpg,  my code is below and thank you for helping.

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data; }

$html = file_get_contents_curl($params['url']);

//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
$urltitle = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
$meta = $metas->item($i);
if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
    $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
    $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image')
    $ogimage = $meta->getAttribute('content');
if($meta->getAttribute('rel') == 'image_src')
    $relimage = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}

 if( empty($ogimage) ) {
$metaimage = $relimage;
} else {
$metaimage = $ogimage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
add this below
Find:

```
$html = file_get_contents_curl($url);
```

Add beow it:

```
 //Change encoding to UTF-8 from ISO-8859-1
    $html = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have to make sure that your url header have `content-type` -> `charset` to *utf-8* or appropriate one. You have to make sure that your url is not content none Ascii character or make sure you have properly set the appropriate *"character’s encoder"*. Maybe i haven’t well understood your problem, however look at this example which have not relation to your code but can be useful:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/services/calculation"; 
    $page = "/services/calculation"; 
    $headers = array( 
        "POST ".$page." HTTP/1.0", 
        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"", 
        "Accept: text/xml", 
        "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
        "Pragma: no-cache", 
        "SOAPAction: \"run\"", 
        "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_data), 
        "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials) 
    ); 

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $defined_vars['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply i found the solution similar to yours i added,
    //Change encoding to UTF-8 from ISO-8859-1
    $html = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $html);
under $html = file_get_contents_curl($url);
now i just need to figure out why i cannot call  rel="image_src" tags